# vue.js: Dynamically add a reactive list of checkboxes based on API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a vue.js component that consists of a search field that queries the Google Places API (removed for simplicity). The response is a list checkboxes with the places. When the user checks a place, I want to set a flag `checked` to `true` on the object which was selected.

However, I also want to make this property reactive, but adding reactive properties at runtime does not work (see https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html).

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <input type="text" ref="complete" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder">
    <fieldset v-if="places" class="checklist">
      <h4>Select your store locations:</h4>
      <div v-for="place in places">
        <input :id="place.id" type="checkbox" v-model="place.checked">
        <label :for="place.id">
          {{ place.name }}<br>
          <span class="subtext">{{ place.formatted_address }}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        places: [],
        api: {
          domain: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
          key: 'API Key',
          libraries: 'places',
        },
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      window.onload = this.loadScript(
        `${this.api.domain}?key=${this.api.key}&libraries=${this.api.libraries}`,
        this.bindAutocomplete
      );
    },
    watch: {
    },
    methods: {
      loadScript(src, callback) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        if (callback) {
          script.onload = callback;
        }
        script.src = src;
      },
      bindAutocomplete() {
        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
          this.$refs.complete
        );
        this.autocomplete.addListener('places_changed', this.pipeAddress);
      },
      pipeAddress() {
        this.places = this.autocomplete.getPlaces();
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

This component works, but I can not programmatically set any checkboxes to "checked", e.g. via `this.places.forEach((place) => { place.checked = true; }`. What would be a proper way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Henning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the `checked` property before the data is observed i.e before it's added to `data`.

One way to do this is by transforming the `places` object in the array returned by `getPlaces()` to include the `checked` property before assigning to a key in `data`.

```
pipeAddress() {
    this.places = this.autocomplete.getPlaces().map(
        place => { place.checked = false; return place }
    );
},
```

Now when the data is observed the checked property will be present and therefore reactive, hence the DOM can update accordingly.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b90zbe4/)

[Explanation](http://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating) from Vue blog:

> When you are adding a new property that wasn’t present when the data was observed. Due to the limitation of ES5 and to ensure consistent behavior across browsers, Vue.js cannot detect property addition/deletions. The best practice is to always declare properties that need to be reactive upfront. In cases where you absolutely need to add or delete properties at runtime, use the global Vue.set or Vue.delete methods.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm. For some reason, I thought I'd have to stub out something like `places[0].checked` for it to be tracked, it seems like the property just has to be there when the assignment happen. Thanks a ton!